# Tensorboard - visualize weights of LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using several LSTM layers to form a deep recurrent neural network. I would like to monitor the weights of each LSTM layer during training. However, I couldn't find out how to attach summaries of the LSTM layer weights to TensorBoard.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

The code is as follows:

```py
cells = []

with tf.name_scope("cell_1"):
    cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.embd_size, state_is_tuple=True, initializer=self.initializer)
    cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell1,
                input_keep_prob=self.input_dropout,
                output_keep_prob=self.output_dropout,
                state_keep_prob=self.recurrent_dropout)
    cells.append(cell1)

with tf.name_scope("cell_2"):
    cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.n_hidden, state_is_tuple=True, initializer=self.initializer)
    cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell2,
                output_keep_prob=self.output_dropout,
                state_keep_prob=self.recurrent_dropout)
    cells.append(cell2)

with tf.name_scope("cell_3"):
    cell3 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.embd_size, state_is_tuple=True, initializer=self.initializer)
    # cell has no input dropout since previous cell already has output dropout
    cell3 = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell3,
                output_keep_prob=self.output_dropout,
                state_keep_prob=self.recurrent_dropout)
    cells.append(cell3)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    cells, state_is_tuple=True)

output, self.final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell,
    inputs=self.inputs,
    initial_state=self.init_state)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell` objects have a [property](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell#variables) called `variables` that works for this. There's just one trick: The property returns an empty list until your cell goes through `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`. At least this is the case when using a single LSTMCell. I can't speak for `MultiRNNCell`. So I expect this would work:

```
output, self.final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(...)
for one_lstm_cell in cells:
    one_kernel, one_bias = one_lstm_cell.variables
    # I think TensorBoard handles summaries with the same name fine.
    tf.summary.histogram("Kernel", one_kernel)
    tf.summary.histogram("Bias", one_bias)
```

And then you probably know how to do it from there, but

```
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(
        "my/preferred/logdir/train", graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    for step in range(1, training_steps+1):
        ...
        _, step_summary = sess.run([train_op, summary_op])
        train_writer.add_summary(step_summary)
```

Looking at the TensorFlow documentation I linked above, there's also a `weights` property. I don't know the difference, if there is any. And, the order of the `variables` return isn't documented. I figured it out by printing the resulting list and looking at the variable names.

Now, `MultiRNNCell` has the same `variables` property according to its [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/MultiRNNCell#variables) and it says it returns *all* layer variables. I honestly don't know how `MultiRNNCell` works, so I cannot tell you whether these are variables belonging exclusively to `MultiRNNCell` or if it includes variables from the cells that go into it. Either way, knowing the property exists should be a nice tip! Hope this helps.

---

Although `variables` is documented for most (all?) RNN classes, it does break for `DropoutWrapper`. The [property has been documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/DropoutWrapper#variables) since r1.2, but accessing the property causes an exception in 1.2 and 1.4 (and looks like 1.3, but untested). Specifically,

```
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
...
lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
wrapped_cell = rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell)
outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(wrapped_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
print("LSTM vars!", lstm_cell.variables)
print("Wrapped vars!", wrapped_cell.variables)
```

will throw `AttributeError: 'DropoutWrapper' object has no attribute 'trainable'`. From the traceback (or a long stare at the [DropoutWrapper source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L684)), I noticed that `variables` is implemented in [DropoutWrapper's super `RNNCell`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L136)'s super [`Layer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py#L202). Dizzy yet? Indeed, we find the documented `variables` property here. It returns the (documented) `weights` property. The `weights` property returns the (documented) `self.trainable_weights + self.non_trainable_weights` properties. And finally the root of the problem:

```
@property
def trainable_weights(self):
    return self._trainable_weights if self.trainable else []

@property
def non_trainable_weights(self):
    if self.trainable:
        return self._non_trainable_weights
    else:
        return self._trainable_weights + self._non_trainable_weights
```

That is, `variables` does not work for a `DropoutWrapper` instance. Neither will `trainable_weights` or `non_trainable_weights` since`self.trainable` is not defined.

One step deeper, `Layer.__init__` defaults `self.trainable` to `True`, but `DropoutWrapper` never calls it. To quote a TensorFlow contributor on [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15810),

> `DropoutWrapper` does not have variables because it does not itself store any. It wraps a cell that may have variables; but it's not clear what the semantics should be if you access the `DropoutWrapper.variables`. For example, all keras layers only report back the variables that they own; and so only one layer ever owns any variable. That said, this should probably return `[]`, and the reason it doesn't is that DropoutWrapper never calls `super().__init__` in its constructor. That should be an easy fix; PRs welcome.

So for instance, to access the LSTM variables in the above example, `lstm_cell.variables` suffices.

---

Edit: To the best of my knowledge, Mike Khan's PR has been incorporated into 1.5. Now, the variables property of the dropout layer returns an empty list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `MultiRNNCell.variables` returns a list with all weights and biases of the LSTM units so I can use it nearly as outlined in your code

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing but am getting an error: 
'DropoutWrapper' object has no attribute 'trainable' maybe it's a problem with my version of Tensorflow, I'm using 1.2.1. Any ideas?

Comment: @MikeKhan Offending line of code? From the error message, your problem doesn't sound related to this question. On the other hand, if calling ``dropoutwrapper.variables`` is causing the issue, maybe it is related.

Comment: @DylanF You're right. Because I'm only using one LSTM layer I wasn't using MultiRNNCell and calling variables on the lstm cell that I got from the dropoutwrapper. 

`lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(number_of_units)`


`lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstm_cell, dropout_output, dropout_input, dropout_state)`

`value, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, input_data, dtype=tf.float32)`

`lstm_weights, lstm_biases = lstm_cell.variables`

Should I wrap my 1 LSTM cell in the MultiRNNCell or is there something else that would make more sense?

Comment: @MikeKhan I can reproduce the error in version 1.4. I'll look into it.

Comment: @MikeKhan See the edit. I would encourage you to ask a new question about this behavior or start an Issue on Github.

Comment: @DylanF I opened a issue on the tensorflow github referencing to your great explanation. Here is a link for reference https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15810

Comment: @MikeKhan Thanks for posting the issue. I've updated my answer to reflect the information you got over there.

Comment: I have come up with a workaround while we wait for the permanent fix.
Instead of calling `one_kernel, one_bias = one_lstm_cell.variables` we can use `one_kernel, one_bias = one_lstm_cell._cell.variables` (note the **._cell**). This calls variables on the original RNNCell passed in. I know it's generally not a good idea to call protected properties but it works.